# Highlighting variables in Eclipse when file isn't part of a project

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

I am wondering how to highlight occurrences of a variable in a java file in Eclipse, but without the file being part of an Eclipse project. Is there a way to do this? I've tried going to:

Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors > Annotations

and changing 'Occurrences' and 'Write Occurrences' doesn't seem to change anything.

Highlighting occurrences works fine only when a file is part of a project. I'm wondering, is there a fix for this when opening a file outside of a project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that the syntax parsing uses the Eclipse compiler and that will only be invoked if it's part of a project or referenced by a project.